# simple ng-include not working. Two errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Going through the pluralsight tutorial, I was introduced the ng-include directive. However, using this directive I ran into a few errors.
 1. XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
 2. Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'

index.html

```
<html ng-app="main">
    <head>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="MainController">
        <h1>{{message}}</h1>

        <div>
            {{error}}
        </div>

        <form name="searchUser" ng-submit="search(username)">
            <input type="search" required placeholder="Username to find" ng-model="username"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>

        <div ng-include="'userdetails.html'" ng-show="user"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

userdetails.html

```
<div>
<h2>Name: {{user.name}}</h2>
<img ng-src="{{user.avatar_url}}" title="{{user.name}}"/>

<select ng-model="repoSortOrder">
    <option value="+name">Name</option>
    <option value="-stargazers_count">Stars</option>
    <option value="+language">Language</option>
</select>   
</div>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Stars</th>
        <th>Language</th>
    </tr>       
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="repo in repos | orderBy: repoSortOrder">
        <td>{{repo.name}}</td>
        <td>{{repo.stargazers_count | number}}</td>
        <td>{{repo.language}}</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you need host your code on some server like LAMP, WAMP, IIS, etc, currently `file://` protocol is messing

Comment: Got it working. Thanks :)

Comment: i'll add an answer whenever i'll be on machine